# Launching a command line application that launches another command line application never responds

Tags: java, 7zip, psexec

When I run the following command from command line, I can run 7-zip as a remote user and extract a file to a network share:

```
C:\PsExec.exe -u username -p password "C:\7z.exe" x -y -o\\network\extractedfiles\ C:\compressed.zip toextract.txt
```

I am running this generated line exactly as my application is running it (note I've altered the directories, paths, username, and passwords so that I can post it online). In fact, the line was copied from my application's logs.

But for some reason, when I run this command from Java using the following code, it sits and waits forever. No file appears on the "\network\extractedfiles\" path.

```
final Process copyFile = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd );
final int exit = copyFile.waitFor();
```

Where cmd is the above string. Any ideas?

More Info 1:

I also meant to say that I noticed when this is run by command line, psexec launches z-zip in a separate command window. Could the problem be that the output from zip is not being disposed of? I tried closing the input stream but it did not seem to fix the problem I'm facing.

More Info 2:

I tried logging out output from the command, and here is what I got:

```
INFO 2012-05-03 15:07:55,188 - Command output: PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
INFO 2012-05-03 15:07:55,188 - Command output: Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
INFO 2012-05-03 15:07:55,188 - Command output: Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
INFO 2012-05-03 15:07:55,188 - Command output:
```

Then it sits forever. When run on the command line the next line of output was:

```
C:\7z.exe exited with error code 0.
```

So it seems 7-zip is hanging. It does not even begin to extract the file though - when I check the directory where the file is expected to extract to nothing appears.

More Info 3:

I created my own unzipper in .net using the ionic.zip.dll. My unzipper was really simple - accepted params through command line, did not have any output. But it still did the exact same thing - unzipping does not start and the execution hangs. Maybe psexec is doing something weird??? Does the fact that psexec wants to run the unzipper in an external command console cause any problems for Java?

Comment: You need to read the output stream of the process, or it will hang forever.  There are several questions here on SO that explain how to do that.

Comment: @EricPetroelje There is a function in the inputstream, outputstream, and errorstream objects named close. Is it enough to "close" the streams? I tried this and it did not fix the problem. See the amendment in my question.

Comment: @EricPetroelje Reading the output of the application did not help. See "More Info 2".

Comment: Are you properly escaping characters in the command string in java before trying to execute it? Maybe this is causing it to interpret your cmd incorrectly. Is 7zip silently waiting for more command line args/input?

Comment: @colinD The -y param makes 7zip assume "yes" for all input (ie - file overwrites), so it should not require any farther input. The command string printed to logs also looks good and worked when I ran it. As an update, I thought it might be something weird with 7zip, so I created my own little unzipper using the ionic.zip .net library. It's really basic - no input no output. It's having the exact same problem. I can't explain it!

Comment: Have you tried using any of the other forms of exec()? specifically the one where you have to tokenize the command string yourself: exec(String[] cmdarray). Have you tried using exec() on a program that does not require command line args?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there was an error you should read the streams from your process to know for sure

Comment: I read the output and there is no error. It just hangs. I added some additional info to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update; I tried creating my own unzipper, psexec, and even my own command line wrapper using C# .net (didn't want to have to remake the entire application), neither of the custom applications have any output, and I the commands being run worked every time from a cmd window running as the foreign user. However, from the Java, it worked once, and then the second time the unzipper froze and never worked again. Seems to be an antivirus or firewall issue. Unfortunately it's out of my hands now, the IT department here is currently assisting us with getting this running, and I've been waiting on a response from them.